# Infinite Loop in Reducer and Epic

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rxjs, ionic4, redux-observable

I've used useDispatch + createAsyncAction + Epic but I'm getting an infinite loop and not really getting why. I'm also use Ionic (don't think it makes a difference)

Call on the component:

```
<IonButton
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch(actions.addMemory.request(dummyMemory));
        }}
      > Dispatch Test</IonButton>
```

Created Action:

```
  "ADD_MEMORY_REQUEST",
  "ADD_MEMORY_SUCCESS",
  "ADD_MEMORY_FAILURE"
)<Memory, Memory, Error>();
```

Epic:

```
  action$
) =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(isActionOf(memoryActions.addMemory.request)),
    mergeMap((action) => {    
      return of(memoryActions.addMemory.success(action.payload));
    })
  );
```

Reducer:

```
      console.log("i got to reducer", action.payload);
      return {
        ...state,
        memories: [...state.memories, action.payload],
      };
```

And I've checked and I'm getting the right payload on the reducer but then it enter in an infinite loop between himself and the epic.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After all the problem was specifying the type of the RootState... I had this on types.d.ts

```
import { StateType, ActionType } from "typesafe-actions";

declare module "typesafe-actions" {
  export type Store = StateType<typeof import("./index").default>;

  export type RootState = StateType<typeof import("./root-reducer").default>;

  export type RootAction = ActionType<typeof import("./root-action").default>;

  interface Types {
    RootAction: RootAction;
  }
}
```

and was missing

```
RootState: RootState;
```

In the types interface...

Now all works!